# AsyncSelect: how to set an initial value?

Tags: react-select, wsaasyncselect

I am using AsyncSelect and need to change the value of the component based on outside logic.
For instance, I have this simple component:

```
import { colourOptions } from '../data';

const filterColors = (inputValue: string) => {
  return colourOptions.filter(i =>
    i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
  );
};

const promiseOptions = inputValue =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(filterColors(inputValue));
    }, 1000);
});

export default class WithPromises extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AsyncSelect cacheOptions defaultOptions loadOptions={promiseOptions} />
   );
  }
}
```

Is there a way to set the initial value of it? I thought of using props but I couldn't figure out how execute onChange event as this would load the options array and set label and value.

Comment: were you able to figure it out? I am trying to do the same and got stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a value like this:

```
<AsyncSelect
  cacheOptions
  defaultOptions
  value={{ label: 'yellow', value: 2 }}
  loadOptions={promiseOptions} />
```

it worked for me.

Comment: hi thank, I use your code it's ok but when changing the value from the menu label and selected item not change?

Comment: Setting a value this way won't let user change the value, plus it depends if we're talking about a controlled component or uncontrolled https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html.
This answer should be downvoted as it's misleading and clearly not the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

When changing the value from the menu options and selected item not change or changed happened based on outside logic then just use the state in `value={yourState}` to set the initial & updated values of AsyncSelect. Selected contain object like `value={value:'', label:''}`

```
const formFields = {
        name: '',
        foo:'',
        bar:''
}
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(formFields);
```

inputs is my state which i used to set the fields values

```
value={inputs.name ? { label: inputs.name } : { label: 'Search customer...' }}
```

I used only label:'Search customer...' to make it look like place holder.

```
<AsyncSelect
    defaultOptions
    value={inputs.name ? { label: inputs.name } : { label: 'Search customer...' }}
    cacheOptions
    onChange={(e) => handleCustomerSelect(e)}
    loadOptions={customerPromiseOptions}
/>
```

here is my onChange which is called when item is select from dropdown menu

```
function handleCustomerSelect(selectedOption) {
    const { value } = selectedOption;
    setInputs({ ...inputs, name:value });
}
```

You can set your initial value from options as well like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/zx29v5488l?file=/index.js)